# Is f continuous at 0 then?

Tags: calculus

If 0<=f(x)<=(sin^2)(x) for every x in R, then f(x) is continuous at
x = 0.

should I check limits when f(x)=0 and f(x)=(sin^2)(x)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the squeezing theorem for limits.

Answer (score 0):

for $$x=0$$ we get $$0\le f(0)\le (\sin(0))^2$$ thus $$f(0)=0$$